# Protect Actuator endpoints with user/password while granting public access for RestControllers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-actuator

I updated an already existing application from Spring Boot 1.3 to 2.0.1. This application makes use of the Actuator and exposes a REST-style API.

In Boot 1.3 the API could be used without authentication and the actuator endpoint was configured to be password protected:

```
security.user.name=foo
security.user.password=bar
security-user.role=ADMIN
```

I updated this like documented in the [configuration changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Configuration-Changelog) and renamed the entries from `security.user.name` to `spring.security.user.name` and alike.

But when I try to `curl` my API, I am denied because I do not provide credentials:
[image: CURL is denied because unauthenticated access was tried]

In the [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4) I found a possible solution how to configure Spring Security on a detailled level:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        // 1
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("status", "info"))
            .permitAll()
        // 2
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .hasRole("ACTUATOR")
        // 3 
        .requestMatchers(StaticResourceRequest.toCommonLocations())
            .permitAll()
        // 4
        .antMatchers("/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
    .and()
  ...
```

but this is more fine-grained than I need and I am looking for an `application.properties` based solution.

Is there a way to solve this without additional code ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you set `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password`, you are configuring form login via `spring-security` for the whole application, including the Actuator endpoints.

Unfortunately, in Spring Boot 2.0 you cannot set a different username/password or disable authentication for the Actuator endpoints using the properties. This means you have to explicitly allow the actuator endpoints through Security configuration.

Through `spring-security`, you can also allow public access to your endpoints and require credentials for the actuator endpoints very easily:

```
@Configuration
public class BasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

(I assumed you were using WebMvc, not WebFlux, which is a bit different)

Verify that you have the following in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=pass
spring.security.user.roles=ACTUATOR,USER   # and others, if you like

management.endpoint.health.roles=ACTUATOR
```

See [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#boot-2x-actuator) for a quick and nice explanation between the differences in Actuator in Spring 1.x vs 2.0.

Comment: And how would this need to look like when I want all other - that means those not equal to `/actuator` - unprotected ?

Comment: This configuration is exactly that! It requires ACTUATOR role only for paths starting with `/actuator`. For everything else, it doesn't require any credentials.

Comment: Today I had the time to finally try this. Unfortunately the REST service is still protected while the Actuator asks for a password too. The class is contained in the JAR but obviously not used / not working. Other classes with @Configuration annotation that I stored in the same package are used and I can see them in the beans.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that this configuration is available as a bean or it won't work. I tested this with 2.0.2.RELEASE. Try making a barebones project to verify.

Comment: How would I write test for just checking the authentication functionality?

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot 2.0, when we override the `configure` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` all existing security backs off and we can provide our custom security. In your case you just need to authenticate the actuator endpoints, which can be done as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").authenticated();
    }

}
```

No changes are required in the `application.properties` file.